# I'm trying to count the number of pages of user uploaded pdf file using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

**Isnt file a blob type itself? Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?**

```js
var input = document.getElementById("customFile");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
reader.onloadend = function(){
    var count = reader.result.match(/\/Type[\s]*\/Page[^s]/g).length;
    console.log('Number of Pages:',count );
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="filename" accept=".pdf" required>
</body>
</html>
```